# cakedc user plugin user_details

Tags: cakedc, cakephp-2.5

I am using CakeDC user plugin with cakephp 2.5. I see that it includes a user_details table. I want this use this table to store the full name of the user among other details.

I have added a new entry into the user_details table with the correct user_id but the table does not get pulled with userData in the view.

On investigating the user model I do not see any association with the user_details such belongsTo. There is actually no user_details model.

There is no mention anywhere what to do here. Do I create a model for the user_details table and create the associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This table is a key-value store and is not used by the plugin any more but kept for legacy apps.

You'll have to add the assocs by extending the plugin or add your own profiles table which I would recommend to use instead of a key-value store, which is actually as well the reason why it was dropped from the plugin.

Comment: Welcome, I'll add this to the documentation as well.

Comment: Added: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/develop/Docs/Documentation/User-Details.md